# Google Fit steps returning for wrong day

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have a user who is experiencing an odd bug but I don't have a pre-existing model or idea of how it's happening and can't replicate it myself. Our app gets from Google Fit's API the previous day's steps value. The user is at GMT +5, but when I test from that time zone I am unable to replicate the issue, nor do my app's other users in GMT +X time zones experience this problem.

At the moment I don't really even know where to start looking/what additional information I can provide to be more helpful about solving this problem. The code that we use to pull the steps value is below. Any help, or even any tips/questions on additional helpful data would be awesome.

***Code Flow***

**Javascript:** It's a hybrid app using PhoneGap, so it starts and ends in javascript. Relevant fields passed are startDate, endDate, and bucket:

```
navigator.health.queryAggregated({
    startDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), // seven days ago
    endDate: new Date(), // now
    dataType: 'steps',
    bucket: 'day'
    }, 
    function(data){
        data.forEach(function(data_entry){
            var date = new Date(data_entry.startDate).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
            steps_record[date] = data_entry.value;
        })
    }
)
```

**Java:** The java code is where the steps value is actually retrieved, the day bucketing determined by startDate/st, endDate/et, and bucket/hasbucket.

```
long st = args.getJSONObject(0).getLong("startDate");
long et = args.getJSONObject(0).getLong("endDate");
String datatype = args.getJSONObject(0).getString("dataType");

boolean hasbucket = args.getJSONObject(0).has("bucket");
boolean customBuckets = false;
String bucketType = "";
if (hasbucket) {
    bucketType = args.getJSONObject(0).getString("bucket");

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.setTimeInMillis(st);
    c.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    c.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    c.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    if (!bucketType.equalsIgnoreCase("hour")) {
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        if (bucketType.equalsIgnoreCase("week")) {
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, c.getFirstDayOfWeek());
        } else if (bucketType.equalsIgnoreCase("month")) {
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        } else if (bucketType.equalsIgnoreCase("year")) {
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
    }
    st = c.getTimeInMillis();

    c.setTimeInMillis(et);
    c.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    c.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    c.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    if (bucketType.equalsIgnoreCase("hour")) {
        c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
    } else {
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        if (bucketType.equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        } else if (bucketType.equalsIgnoreCase("week")) {
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
        } else if (bucketType.equalsIgnoreCase("month")) {
            c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        } else if (bucketType.equalsIgnoreCase("year")) {
            c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        }
    }
    et = c.getTimeInMillis();
}

DataReadRequest.Builder builder = new DataReadRequest.Builder();
builder.setTimeRange(st, et, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
int allms = (int) (et - st);

if (hasbucket) {
    if (bucketType.equalsIgnoreCase("hour")) {
        builder.bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } else if (bucketType.equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
        builder.bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } else {
        // use days, then will need to aggregate manually
        builder.bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
} else {
    builder.bucketByTime(allms, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: "`6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), // seven days ago`" are you sure this is right?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://myfitnesspal.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/16352265-google-fit-steps-logged-on-the-wrong-day), make sure that your timezone settings on both sides are matched and correct for your current location as well as any variation in Daylight Savings Time in your region.

Here's a related thread which might also help: [Google FIT api returns different step counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546979/google-fit-api-returns-different-step-counts)